# Typescript -> 'value' is of type 'unknown'. in a React Native project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am converting a JS file to TS, in my react native project but have stumbled accross this issue that I can't resolve where the `value['flag']` is showing the following error,
'value' is of type 'unknown'.ts(18046). Any idea on how to solve this will be much appreciated.

The code block is the following:

```
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(orderedCities)) {
      if (
        key.startsWith(userInput.toLowerCase()) &&
        userInput != '' &&
        value !== typeof undefined
      ) {
        const inputObject = {city: '', flag: ''};
        inputObject.city = key;
        inputObject.flag = value['flag'];
        creationArray.push(inputObject);
        setElementArray(creationArray);
      }
    }
```

I tried declaring a type in the const [key, value] but this triggers a different error, I added the `value !== typeof undefined` but this has not changed the error showen.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are expecting `value` to be an object with a property `{ flag: string }`.  Right now the entire `value` has type `unknown`.  It's not even know that it is an `object`.

This means that **something is wrong with the type of your `orderedCities` variable**.  That is, the problem is somewhere higher up in your code.

Perhaps you initialized an empty dictionary without declaring its type.  I can reproduce your `'value' is of type 'unknown'` error if I create `orderedCities` as:

```
const orderedCities = {};
```

I can get rid of the error by creating `orderedCities` with a proper type:

```
const orderedCities: Record<string, { flag: string }> = {};
```

---

You will want to remove your attempted solution `&& value !== typeof undefined`.  This doesn't make sense as `typeof undefined` is a `string`. It will give you an error of its own once you have a proper type on `orderedCities`.

---

Corrected code:

```
// Dummy variables with correct types to avoid errors
const creationArray: Array<{ city: string; flag: string }> = [];
const setElementArray: (array: Array<{ city: string; flag: string }>) => void = () => { };
const userInput = '';

// THIS IS THE TYPE WHICH MATTERS
const orderedCities: Record<string, { flag: string }> = {};

// No errors in your code
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(orderedCities)) {
    if (
        key.startsWith(userInput.toLowerCase()) &&
        userInput != ''
    ) {
        const inputObject = { city: '', flag: '' };
        inputObject.city = key;
        inputObject.flag = value['flag'];
        creationArray.push(inputObject);
        setElementArray(creationArray);
    }
}
```

[TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBEFcFtoT1ANwIYCcCWyBGAbApgM6gDu6ALgBagDGA9qqntWaGXAA6Gu2jKK3oAJqDwN6BALAAoOgDsCLao2Rl0tWQEEGyOAC5QW1DoA8Abxrk9oBRlkBzANygAZjmR39N9PdABfAHygALygANoAug7ScgrWeGQAovjQeLJkhjr6ABRoRlYZcGYWbJ5kto4ubh7WZd52fv4AlMGB-ELBoFnNQYHmvlEy6rGQBKIAkrLskCwhAOSzA9IgoAAqABJjAMqgW6trCasAmgAKBwDqGwDCa6AAshorKwkASpvRQyz0gqJ4gpfk6EI%20meTC%20xi89gANKBzK53KVyg0OqZ%20tIlmAAHI8USocSgbygOC0SCoGi0b7SZz0ToxFihADWeDg0JQOEgeHCoFozlAAHksAArJhkAB0qVqhCyXx%20fwBhEazVM0lAKvxPKyytVWsZcBFCjQZAIZ3IFCyI3Gk2mIrItAAMrRiKJLshRl1mgAyd2arUq82oCZTFgAQjms29oEV4a1tPxlrI-KFzGRxSs82hcOq8z8Ax9qu8gYTwpF1EsHR1OdzsYLgqLGY6rPZoVmGdmkSjqqUeBUak02l1UwIpvz00LzEaFdzo0SyXFBSyne76gK4-DvmkviAA)

Answer (score 0):

Use `for..in` when you wan to iterate over object.

```
for (const key in orderedCities) {
  // const k = key as keyof typeof orderedCities
  // const value = orderedCities[k]
  // or
  const value = orderedCities[key as keyof typeof orderedCities]

  // ...
}
```